# preventDefault prevents scrolling

Tags: javascript

I've created a responsive site that users can bookmark to their home screen. On a tablet and phone it would be nice if when the user scrolls to the top of the page or to the bottom of the page the screen doesn't do that thing where if you scroll too far down or too far up you see a bit of grey behind the page and it snaps back.

I know that using 'preventDefault' on the body will make this happen, however doing so now prevents the user from scrolling at all.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.ontouchmove = function(e){e.preventDefault();}
});
```

Here is the html call:

```
<body ontouchmove="touchMove(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you capture the eventand only call preventDefault is it is in a certain viewport / scrollTop position..  (will try and add code shortly).

This should help you get the scroll top position of the current document

```
function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers
        return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
        var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
        return D.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

Then call preventDefault only if scrollTop is at the top...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      document.ontouchmove = function(e){ if (getScrollTop() != document.scrollTop)      
          {
             e.preventDefault();
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: I dumped your code into my javascript file, but didn't have a chance to really look at why it wasn't working. I'll see if I can get it to work tomorrow. Thanks for spending the time writing it.